# How does html5-script-attribute "data-main" work?

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs, custom-data-attribute

For example requireJS uses following syntax:

```
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

and in its documentation you can read:

> data-main attribute tells require.js to load scripts/main.js after
>   require.js loads

1. How is that (script load-order) possible?
2. If the name of the js-file was nomain.js, would the data-attribute be "data-nomain" ?
3. I see no information about that in the html5 specification or am I looking at wrong place?

thank you

Comment: This is why "foo" and "bar" were invented, to distinguish user names from system names.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> How is that (script load-order) possible?

Because that is the purpose of `require.js` which consists of rather a lot of code to do that.

That specific part is rather trivial, `require.js` can't do anything (including load another script) until it is loaded itself.

> If the name of the js-file was nomain.js, would the data-attribute be "data-nomain" ?

No. [Require looks at `data-main`](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/blob/master/require.js#L1966) to determine the entry point script file. It gets the URL from the value of that attribute.

> I see no information about that in the html5 specification or am I looking at wrong place?

`data-*` attributes are defined in the section [3.2.5.9 Embedding custom non-visible data with the data-* attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes)